# Java Generics Value.<SomeValue>

Tags: java, generics

I had an interview test and saw the following code:

EDIT:

```
public class TestValue {
    private Value<SomeValue> defaultValue;

    @Test
    public void Empty_Value_Has_No_Value() {
        Assert.assertFalse(Value.<SomeValue> createEmptyValue()
            .hasValue());
    }

    @Test
    public void Default_Value_IsEmpty() {
        Assert.assertEquals(Value.<SomeValue> createEmptyValue(),
            defaultValue);
    }

    @Test
    public void Non_Empty_Value_Has_Value() {
        Assert.assertTrue(new Value<SomeValue>(true, new SomeValue())
            .hasValue());
    }
}
```

I had never seen Java generic like

```
Value.<SomeValue>
```

The test is to implement Value class with the given unit test code above.

I tried to figure out the Value method signature below (need implementation):

```
public interface Value<T> {

    public boolean hasValue();
    public Value<T> createEmptyValue();
}
```

Any one know, please help?

Thank you

EDIT: Should be like this according to answers below @marlon

```
public class Value<T> {

    public boolean hasValue(){}
    public static <M> Value<M> createEmptyValue(){}; //need <M>
}
```

The key syntax to know:

```
Value.<SomeValue>  //ClassName.<Type>method
```

is way to invoke static method of a class with parameterized argument.

EDIT: according to @snipes83, syntax to invoke non-static method of a class with parameterized argument.

```
SomeObject.<Type>method
```

Comment: It could be a typo? `Value<SomeValue>.createEmptyValue()` makes more sense.

Comment: Was that a whiteboard coding?
Maybe it is only a reference to a type which can be anything by definition, just meaning they provide a value of that type, but the type doesn't really matter?

That's what I would assume in that case.

Comment: Yeah; kind of curious myself.

Comment: I made some research and there are actually cases where you need to use the `SomeObject.<Type>method`-syntax without the method beeing static. See my answer for an explanation.

Comment: The `.<T>method` syntax has nothing to do with the method being static or the type having a type argument. It **only** aplies if the *method* has a type argument (that can not be inferred)!

Answer (score 6):

`Value.<SomeValue>` it's the way generics are represented for methods.

Using Google Guava's `Optional` as an example:

```
Optional<String> email = Optional.<String>of(strEmail);
```

See [Generic Types - Invoking generic methods](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/javaian5_chap04/index1.html)

Since interfaces cannot declare static methods (shame on you java), just declare your method as static and forget about the interface, like this:

```
class Value<T> {

    public static <T> Value<T> createEmptyValue(){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean createEmptyValue() in the above should be static? like public static Value<T> createEmptyValue(); //compile error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type T

Comment: @Eric: Almost, but you'd parameterize the static method on `<T>`, like `public static <T> Value<T> createEmptyValue() {...}`. As the compiler is pointing out, you can't reference a non-static parameter T on the class from a static method.

Comment: @Eric,Ryan Stewart Updated my answer to reflect your comments.

Comment: Static has nothing to do with it, although in this case it appears to be a statics method. Both instance and static methods may be typed

Answer (score 3):

Look at the class `Test` with the method `getEmptyList` below:

```
public class Test {
    public <T> List<T> getEmptyList() {
        return new ArrayList<T>();
    }
}
```

It returns an empty `List` containing objects of type `T`.

If you use `Test` like this

```
Test t = new Test();
List<Integer> list = t.getEmptyList();
```

Then the type inference mechanism is able to infer the type parameter based on the variable type.

However if you need to use the return value of `getEmptyList` within a method invocation expression like in the following example where the method `printList` expects a single argument of type `List<Integer>`, then the type can not be infered from any variable type.

```
public void printList(List<Integer> list) {
    for (int i : list) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
}

printList(t.getEmptyList()); // This will FAIL.
```

In this case you need to specify the type using  the following:

```
printList(t.<Integer>getEmptyList());
```

Answer (score 2):

**1)** This is how generic methods are invoked. Refer >> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html

**2)** `<SomeValue>` in `Value.<SomeValue>` is **optional**. Compiler can infer the type. This is called *TypeInference*. Refer >> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

**Answer Updated:**

**3)** `Value.<SomeValue> createEmptyValue()` is right and `Value.<SomeValue>createEmptyValue()` is right too. Both ways are legal. Just tested it. Didn't notice before.

Comment: As it is currently written, the only difference between the two examples given in number (3) is the whitespace; could you elaborate on the supposed difference?

Comment: Awww, just tested it. It does work. Damn it, didn't notice before.

Answer (score 1):

Although `Value` is itself obviously typed ( based on the instance variable type of `Value<SomeValue>`), the static `createEmptyValue()` method is also typed.

A reasonable assumption, if naming conventions have been adhered to, is that `SomeValue` extends (or implements) `Value`.

Although there us no one correct answer, a likely possibility for the signature of `Value` is:

```
public class Value<T extend Value> {
    public static <V extends Value> V createEmptyValue() {
        // some impl
    }
}
```